# Induction on Directed Acyclic Graphs with Root / Polytree

Tags: graph-theory, induction, transfinite-induction

Assume $G$ is a directed acyclic graph (DAG) with one root node $u$.

This makes $G$ a polytree, a DAG whose underlying undirected graph is a tree.

Let's say we want to prove that statement $P$ holds for all nodes of $G$.

**Question**:

Does the following induction principle hold:

$$P(u) \; \text{and} \; \forall v \in G\colon \big(\forall w \in G\colon [w \in \text{parents}(v) \implies P(w)] \implies P(v)\big)$$
$$\implies \forall v \in G\colon P(v)$$

I.e. $P$ holds for the root, and if $P$ holds for all parents of $v$, then $P$ holds for $v$.

**Attempt to proof:**

Consider it as a special case of [Noetherian Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation#Induction_and_recursion).

We need to construct a well-founded relation.

Let $w \prec v$, if there is a directed path from $w$ to $v$.

This partial order is called [reachability relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph#Mathematical_properties).

In particular, $w \in \text{parents}(v) \implies w \prec v$.

I think the following implication holds: $$\big(\forall w \in G\colon [w \in \text{parents}(v) \implies P(w)] \implies P(v)\big) \implies \big(\forall w \in G\colon [w \prec v \implies P(w)] \implies P(v)\big)$$

Note that a node can have an infinite number of parents or children.

Thus, it remains to show that $\prec$ is well-founded, that each non-empty subset of nodes has a minimal element with respect to $\prec$.
This could follow from the property that $G$ is a directed tree (with root node $u$). There are no infinite descending chains.

Comment: In a polytree, a node has at most one parent (only roots have no parents), and it may have multiple roots, so I don't think you talk about a polytree, but just about a DAG with a single root.

Comment: If your graph is finite, you can do an induction on the topological order. In your case, I think you can do an induction on the depths of the nodes (their distance to the root).